# has and belong to many stuff on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

i've created 2 tables domaine and startup. I also create a join table domaine_startup and i've linked this 2 tables with has_and_belong_to method. In my new startup i've allow user to select a domaine and now i wanna get a domaine id ant put it on domaine_startup. I did this:

create methode:

```
  def create
@startup = Startup.new(params[:startup])
@joindre.domaine_id=(params[:domaine])
@joindre.startup_id=(params[:startup])

respond_to do |format|
  if @startup.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@startup, :notice => 'Startup was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @startup, :status => :created, :location => @startup }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @startup.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

and this is the new methode:

```
  def new
@startup = Startup.new
@domaines = Domaine.all
@joindre = domaine_startup.new
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @startup }
end
```

end
but i got the following error:undefined local variable or method `domaine_startup' for #

How can i fix it? (sorry for my bad english)
edit
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
the following is my models files:

domaines:

```
class Domaine < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :startups
end
```

startups:

```
class Startup < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :domaines
end
```

Comment: I think you are not understanding the join table concept. Can you edit this question and show your models? Then we can better help you. Also, see the [Rails Guide for Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: i just add a models files. Can you take a look? thank you

Comment: Mark Thomas can you please help me, i did what you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark Thomas said, definitely read through the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) he posted.

In your `new` method, you're attempting to create a new object of type `domaine_startup`, and you're receiving an error (I am assuming the error is in this method, but you have not displayed the full error message so it is impossible to say for certain). I'm guessing the name is misspelled; perhaps it is `Domaine_startup` or `DomainStartup`? Remember that in Ruby, class names and other constants must begin with a capital letter, while method names and variables begin with a lowercase. This is not merely a coding convention, it is mandatory. So ultimately, Ruby is attempting to search for a method or variable with that lowercase name, rather than the proper class name, which was your intention.

In regards to your `create` method, I'm not quite sure where your `@joindre` object is coming from, but I have a feeling you believe it still exists from when it was created in the `new` method. You must remember that those methods are executed separately, from two separate actions, and once the action is finished processing, everything is cleared up and gone. In other words, `@joindre` doesn't exists any more in the `create` method.

I would recommend doing the following instead:

```
@startup = Startup.new(params[:startup])
@startup.domaines << Domaine.new(params[:domaine]) # Create new Domaine
```

Or, if the domaine is already in the database:

```
@startup = Startup.new(params[:startup])
@startup.domaines << Domaine.find(params[:domaine]) # Retrieve existing Domaine
```

This is the simplest method to add a new `Domaine` object to the `Startup` object's list of domaines.